# Rails 3: Undefined method after adapting existing sqlite db

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, methods, undefined, rails-console

In rails console doing User.first and Post.first works fine. Post.first.user works fine but User.first.posts gives me an Undefined method error

The models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :role :user_email, :user_name

    has_many :posts
end
```

and

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :content, :status, :title, :user_id

    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments
end
```

When I create a new project everything works fine but in this case I did something different. I adapted an existing database (sqlite) from another web application (non-rails) to the rails. What I did was rename columns to fit rails conventions and where previously I was using user name as unique key and used that to link to post owners I changed the column name to user_id and updated all the values to the relevant user id. I changed the column type and values to int values too.

Same goes for Comment: Comment.first.post works but Post.commments gives the undefined method error.

When doing User.joins(:post(s)) I get the error "Association named 'posts' was not found" but Post.joins(:user) works fine.

> Edit:
>   Shame on me - I left out relevant information I didn't think was relevant.
>
> Anyway - I had a column called role so the User model had attr_accessible :role --- once > I removed that everything worked like intended.
>
> I however don't understand why this should make a difference. This: > https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization user model has :role and I > would assume any user based app would have has_many dependency and thus fail like mine did.
>
> ... or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Have you changed the table name too?

Comment: adding on what @MurifoX, Specifically Post -> Posts

Comment: Yes, table name is posts. I basically ran generate for all the models in a vanilla app, then renamed the tables and columns in the old db to match everything in the generated one and then renamed the db file.

Comment: Shame on me - I left out relevant information I didn't think was relevant.

Anyway - I had a column called role so the User model had attr_accessible :role --- once I removed that everything worked like intended.

I however don't understand why this should make a difference. This: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization user model has :role and I would assume any user based app would have has_many dependency and thus fail like mine did.

... or is there something else I'm missing?